# Webpack, extract text plugin and relative paths of resources of images and fonts

Tags: webpack

In webpack I need to extract bundled CSS files to a different folder than my JS files and the same thing applies for images and fonts. Result should be:

```
build/
    js/
        bundle.js
    styles/
        css/
            bundle.css
        fonts/
            ...
    images/
        ...
```

I tried many combinations of webpack config but I could not get it to generate this file structure and in the same time generate correct relative URLs in the CSS files.

I ended up with this config:

```
var ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');

var appCssExtractPlugin = new ExtractTextPlugin('styles/css/styles.css');

module.exports = {
    entry: {
        app: __dirname + '/src/client/app/bootstrap.js',
    },
    output: {
        path: __dirname + '/build',
        publicPath: '',
        filename: 'js/bundle.js'
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components|sc\.js$)/,
                loaders: ['ng-annotate', 'babel?presets[]=es2015']
            },
            {
                test: /\.scss$/,
                exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
                loader: appCssExtractPlugin.extract([], ['css', 'resolve-url', 'sass'])
            },
            {
                test: /\.html$/,
                loader: 'html'
            },
            {
                test: /\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png)$/,
                loader: 'url?limit=10000&name=[name].[ext]?[hash]'
            },
            {
                test: /\.(woff|woff2|svg|ttf|eot|otf)$/,
                loader: 'file?name=[name].[ext]?[hash]'
            }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        appCssExtractPlugin,
    ]
};
```

This does not work - the output file structure is correct, but in bundle.css the URLs to the images and fonts are wrong and not relative to the CSS file:

```
url(styles/fonts/abc.woff)
url(images/abc.gif)
```

Can anybody help me to setup the correct config? I am running out of ideas for combinations of path, publicPath, extract plugin path, url/file loader file name...

Comment: Did you find a resolution for this?

Answer (score 0):

Your public path should be `/` instead of an empty string.

You have to enable sourceMap in your sass loader `sass?sourceMap`. See https://github.com/bholloway/resolve-url-loader#source-maps-required